# Unhandled Exception: setState() called after dispose(): in flutter

Tags: flutter, setstate, dispose

I'm trying to change the value of a variable using `setState` but it gives me this error

```
Unhandled Exception: setState() called after dispose(): _SplashState#27d6e(lifecycle state: defunct, not mounted, ticker inactive)
E/flutter (12289): This error happens if you call setState() on a State object for a widget that no longer appears in the widget tree (e.g., whose parent widget no longer includes the widget in its build). This error can occur when code calls setState() from a timer or an animation callback.
E/flutter (12289): The preferred solution is to cancel the timer or stop listening to the animation in the dispose() callback. Another solution is to check the "mounted" property of this object before calling setState() to ensure the object is still in the tree.
E/flutter (12289): This error might indicate a memory leak if setState() is being called because another object is retaining a reference to this State object after it has been removed from the tree. To avoid memory leaks, consider breaking the reference to this object during dispose().
```

Because of the above error i'm not getting notification on my screen.

In `initState` function, i'm doing to get the notifications and `firebase token` and storing the values to `sharedPreference`. I want a specific value to be stored in variable so i can access the updated value on other screen on tap on notification.

here is my code

```
class Splash extends StatefulWidget {
  const Splash({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _SplashState createState() => _SplashState();
}

class _SplashState extends State<Splash> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController controller;
  late Animation heartbeatAnimation;

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
 controller = AnimationController(
        vsync: this, duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500));
    heartbeatAnimation =
        Tween<double>(begin: 100.0, end: 250.0).animate(controller);
    controller.forward().whenComplete(() {
      controller.reverse();
    });


    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3), () async {
      FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
        print("onMessage Clicked!");
       
        String getId = message.data["id"];
        print("ride id get:    ${message.data["id"]}");
        if (mounted) {     
          setState(() {
            bookedRideId = int.parse(getId);   //this line is not wwrking, error points here
          });
        }
        RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
        AndroidNotification? android = message.notification?.android;
        if (notification != null && android != null) {
          flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
              notification.hashCode,
              notification.title,
              notification.body,
              NotificationDetails(
                android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
                  channel.id,
                  channel.name,
                  icon: android.smallIcon,
                ),
              ));
        }
      });
    
      getToken();

      FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(
          _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);

      // assign channel (required after android 8)
      await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
          .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
              AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
          ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);

      // initialize notification for android
      var initialzationSettingsAndroid =
          AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');
      var initializationSettings =
          InitializationSettings(android: initialzationSettingsAndroid);
      flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings);

      final NotificationAppLaunchDetails? notificationAppLaunchDetails =
          await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
              .getNotificationAppLaunchDetails();

      
      payload = notificationAppLaunchDetails!.payload;
      if (payload != null) {
        routeToGo = '/second';
        navigatorKey.currentState?.pushNamed('/second');
      }

      await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
          onSelectNotification: selectNotification);

      FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp
          .listen((RemoteMessage message) async {
        print(message.notification!.body != null);
        if (message.notification!.body != null) {
          print("=======================rideid=====================");
          print(rideId);
          navigatorKey.currentState?.pushNamed('/second');
        }
      });

     

      SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      
      emailAddress = prefs.getString('email').toString();
      token = prefs.getString('token').toString();
      emailAddress == "null" && token == "null"
          ? Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const PreLogin()),
              (route) => false)
          : role == "driver"
              ? Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => DriverHome()),
                  (route) => false)
              : Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const UserHome()),
                  (route) => false);
    });

   
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();

    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
          resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
          body: Container(
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage(splashBgImage),
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
              ),
            ),
            child: const Logo(),
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: overriding dispose method help me to resolve this error .

Answer (score 1):

Your `initState()` method contains too many complex logic codes and needs to be reformatted.

The specific error `setState() called after dispose()` occurs because the app has changed to another page before calling the `setState()` method of the current page.

Combined with the code above, this code snippet changes the app to another page

```dart
      SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

      emailAddress = prefs.getString('email').toString();
      token = prefs.getString('token').toString();
      emailAddress == "null" && token == "null"
          ? Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const PreLogin()),
              (route) => false)
          : role == "driver"
              ? Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => DriverHome()),
                  (route) => false)
              : Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const UserHome()),
                  (route) => false);
```

before this code snippet

```dart
    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3), () async {
      FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
        print("onMessage Clicked!");

        String getId = message.data["id"];
        print("ride id get:    ${message.data["id"]}");
        if (mounted) {
          setState(() {
            bookedRideId =
                int.parse(getId); //this line is not wwrking, error points here
          });
        }
// ..
```

which calls the `setState()` method.

Comment: how to fix this issue than? i'm trying to calling the code snippet which change the app screen after setState but my splash screen keep stuck now.

Comment: @TimeToCode It depends on your business logic requirement. In my opinion, you need to separate your login judge from your page change responding to the business message.

Comment: On the splash page(aka a welcome page), what you can do is just check if the user has logined or not, and turn to the login page or the home page.

Comment: The business message handling stuff should not be contained in the splash page, and the business data should definitely not be stored in the splash page(its lifecycle is short, and cannot respond to all the following messages. The error message is complaining to this)

Comment: i was checking this, is user was logged in or not on splash screen, but then later the notification requirement  came so i'm adding logic of notification on splash screen  too. and then on the behalf on notification, when user tap on it should redirect to a  other screen

Comment: please suggest how to do this, how to get from it.

Comment: You want to make users stay in splash page. No matter he is logined or not?

Comment: If this is what you want, then your change is right ` i'm trying to calling the code snippet which change the app screen after setState but my splash screen keep stuck now`. You should continue the way to investigate the problem in the firebase notification.

Comment: One more thing, I cannot see `bookedRideId ` & `mounted` variable definition. If `bookedRideId ` is not related to this page, I think maybe you should just pass it to another page and use it there. Again, do not make business logic data get related to a page that is build with a not compatible lifecycle.

Comment: ```bookedRideId``` is global variable, and yes i want my app start from splash no matter it is logged in or not. plus the notification is not coming from firebasee, it is linked with an api, when i hit one API the notification api automatically call, this is what handle from backend.

Comment: Is the notification a prerequisite for a user to be routed to another page?

Comment: yes, i meant when user tap on notification it should redirect to a screen. i want to do this becuase from notification im getting a particular data and on the behalf of that i'm calling an API

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245906/discussion-between-lebecca-and-timetocode).

Answer (score 0):

if you want to `setState({})` anonymously like from provider broadcastStream listener callback, you must wait for your widget to be mounted, but some time

`if(mounted){// your  code }`  isn't enough to do the trick so it will cause a memory leak problem. the solution is to create an async function to run your code and set state from there. the life cycle of a widget must be obeyed all the time. Any anonymous request to sate state in another widget wait untill that widget is mounted so you must delay setState({})  fotr a few seconds and check the widget is mounted, then set state. Lets say your using provider to set a message to  a stream subscription to set a certain state  lets say a future, your code would look like this

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
 late  Future<demo> demoFuture;
   late StreamSubscription uiSubscription;
  @override
  void initState() {

    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    demoFuture = getDemoFuture();
       final applicationBloc =
        Provider.of<MyDemoBloc>(context, listen: false);
    uiSubscription = applicationBloc.uiCommunication.stream
        .asBroadcastStream()
        .listen((message) async {
updateMyFuture();

        });
  }

  void updateMyFuture(){
    /// your code
       Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2), () async {
           setState(() {
              demoFuture = getDemoFuture();
           });
       });
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Placeholder();
  }
}
```